# jQuery do something after toggle() complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `scroll` functions, I would like to do something after `toggle` is finished. Currently I have issue of my function execute multiple times because it fires on `scroll`.

**Pseudo flow:**

// If div visible on scroll hide

// If scroll position 63 or more add class

// If scroll position less than 63 add / remove class

My Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

        // If search open on scroll hide
        if($('.filter').length > 0){
            if($('.search').is( ":visible" )){

                $('.search').toggle("slow");
                $('.search').hide();
            }
        }

        // Add Fixed position when position 63
        if($('.filter').length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() >= 63){

            if($('.search').is( ":visible" )){

                $('.search').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
                    $('.search').hide();
                });

            }

            // Set fixed 
            $('.filter').addClass('fixed-position');

        }

        // Remove fixed on 61
        if($('.filter').length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() <= 61 && $('.filter').hasClass('fixed-position')){

            $('.filter').removeClass('fixed-position');

        }

    });
```

So I tried if first IF to hide search so that it doesn't execute that IF statement as I continue to scroll. (Failed)

In second IF I tried to use different function from jQuery website but result is the same.

I am open to suggestions, 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your code, it makes sense that your function is executed multiple times (more times than you want).

Quick and easy solution to prevent multiple function calls is to keep track of when your function is executed using a boolean variable and then resetting that variable appropriately so your function gets called again when some event occurs again.

Either than or you take a different approach to this issue.